# Ram usage of model keep increasing when training to previously trained model

Tags: keras, tensorflow

**Update**
It keep increasing when i load the saved model like this.

```
return tf.keras.models.load_model("models/min__1576172002.model")
```

and i am saving model using

```
   agent.model.save(f'models/min__{int(time.time())}.model')
```

---

I declare my model as

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6,activation='relu',input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then its working ok.
But after some time as it was not showing results, I use

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6,activation='relu',input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I added only one more layer. But now. 
I see RAM usage of computer. It is keep increasing and not stopping. If i pause training then RAM will also pause at that point and when i continue training  then RAM will increase and it took **32GB of RAM** (and still increasing )and previous model with one less layer took only **6GB of RAM**

Comment: Maybe share more parts  of the code?

Comment: @YohanesAlfredo I found that this problem is happening only when i load previously trained model and then train it again.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I wanted to train a model N times to see how it varies from run to run. I was re-declaring the model and storing it in the same variable thinking that the garbage collector would clean it up. However, tensorflow doesn't work like that. It created a new computational graph each time ever increasing my RAM usage. I don't know if this helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found it and answering as it might help somebody.

I saw pattern in this problem. Every time I load the model from my saved ones and then start them training again it will start eating my ram. Slowly it will reach to limit of my laptop.
But same model if i train from scratch will not do same. 
I was loading model using

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("models/min__1576172002.model")
```

So Instead of training it again. I Build a new one and assign its weights = trained models weight. This way this problem is solved.

```
        prev_modal = tf.keras.models.load_model("models/min__1576224504.h5")
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(6,activation='relu',input_shape=(4,)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        # model.add(Flatten())

        model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        # model.add(Flatten())

        model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))


        model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

        model.set_weights(prev_modal.get_weights())
```